# Encoding issues related to Python and foreign languages

Tags: python-3.x, unicode, encoding, byte, decoding

Here's a problem I am facing with encoding and decoding texts.

I am trying to write a code that finds a 'string' or a 'byte' in a file, and return the path of the file.

Currently, since the files I am opening have encoding of 'windows-1252' or 'cp-1252', so I have been trying to:
1. encode my string into a byte corresponding to the encoding of the file
2. match the file and get the path of that file

I have a file, say 'f', that has the encoding of 'windows-1252' or 'cp-1252'. It includes a text that is in Chinese: `'[跑Online農場]'`

```
with open(os.path.join(root, filename), mode='rb') as f:
    text = f.read()
    print(encoding(text)) # encoding() is a separate function that I wrote that returns the encoding of the file
    print(text)
```

```
Windows-1252
b'\x00StaticText\x00\x00\x12\x00[\xb6]Online\xb9A\xb3\xf5]\x00\x01\x00\x ...
```

As you may see, the 'binary' texts for `[跑Online農場]` is `[\xb6]Online\xb9A\xb3\xf5]`

However, the funny thing is that if I literally convert the string into bytes, I get:

```
enter_text = '[跑Online農場]'
print(bytes(enter_text, 'cp1252'))
```

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u8dd1' in position 1: character maps to <undefined>
```

On the other hand, opening the file using

```
with open(os.path.join(root, filename), mode='r', encoding='cp-1252') as f ...
```

I get:

```
StaticText   [¶]Online¹A³õ]   €?‹  Œ  î...
```

which I am not sure how I would 'translate' `'[跑Online農場]'` into `'[¶]Online¹A³õ]'`. Answer to this may also solve the problem

What should I do to correctly 'encode' the Chinese/Foreign characters so that it matches the 'rb' bytes that the Python returns?

Thank you!

Comment: My first guess was that the data are encoded with GBK, but `b'[\xb6]Online\xb9A\xb3\xf5]'.decode('gbk')` returns `'[禲Online笰初]'`, which gets the distribution of Latin and Chinese characters right, but the Chinese ones aren't correct.

Comment: Maybe there's another encoding similar to GBK...

Comment: There is a lot in your questions, and a lot is already answered. But the most nerving is "foreign characters". English language has much more then few alphanumeric characters and few other characters you find in ASCII or in "ANSI". Pro-tip: always include the encoding. Also `print` has an implicit encoding (OS dependent), and on Windows console often does not support full unicode range, so your error. Write to a file, or look about printing Unicode strings in Windows (there are already many questions and answers)

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi your comments apply to a lot of "encoding error" posts, but not really to this one. The OP is already reading from a file and explicitly specifying the encoding. The UnicodeEncodeError doesn't come from `print()`, but from the call to `bytes()` with the wrong codec. The OP is apparently quite encoding-aware; their error is mainly in trusting the `encoding` function, which guesses wrong.

Comment: Thank you for your comments! As a note, I used ```UniversalDetector from chardet library``` to 'guess' the encoding of the text that I am importing to Python for work. I found out that the Chinese characters are encoded using 'cp950' as @lenz noticed, but the other texts that aren't Chinese cannot be decoded. I believe the only task left is to either find a code that 'filter out' the texts that aren't encoded in cp950, or find another way out of this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `encoding` function is wrong: the codec of the file is probably CP950, but certainly not CP1252.

Note: guessing the encoding of a given byte string is always approximate.
There's no safe way of determining the encoding for sure.

If you have a byte string like

```
b'[\xb6]Online\xb9A\xb3\xf5]'
```

and you know it must translate (be decoded) into

```
'[跑Online農場]'
```

then what you can is trial and error with a few codecs.

I did this with the [list of codecs supported by Python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings), searching for codecs for Chinese.

When using CP-1252 (the Windows version of Latin-1), as you did, you get mojibake:

```
>>> b'[\xb6]Online\xb9A\xb3\xf5]'.decode('cp1252')
'[¶]Online¹A³õ]'
```

When using CP-950 (the Windows codepage for Traditional Chinese), you get the expected output:

```
>>> b'[\xb6]Online\xb9A\xb3\xf5]'.decode('cp950')
'[跑Online農場]'
```

So: use CP-950 for reading the file.

Comment: Thank you for finding the right codec for me! I sincerely appreciate it. I just wanted to say that if I use the ```.decode('cp950')```, I get a ```UnicodeDecodeError: 'cp950' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 37: illegal multibyte sequence```. We are very close to solving the problem; what would you suggest to solve this issue?

Comment: (I get the ```UnicodeDecodeError``` for the texts that are not written in Chinese)

Comment: There's no general answer to this. Maybe you can find (through trial and error) another encoding that works correctly for all text, but it's also possible that your file has mixed encodings, ie. some parts (rows?) were encoded with a different encoding than others. That's the approach taken by [ftfy](https://pypi.org/project/ftfy/) (Note: that library also got your `'[跑Online農場]'` example wrong). You need to carefully analyse your data – if you can't fix the source.

Comment: Btw, if this answer helped you, consider upvoting and/or accepting it (see the upwards pointing triangle and the check mark to the left of my post). That's how people say "thank you" on Stack Overflow :)

Comment: ```Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.``` :c